# Can we use SDKs directly in Suitelet?

Tags: amazon-s3, netsuite

Implementing a requirement to store images in AWS bucket instead of NetSuite. Since the bucket is private, I have to upload and generate the URL in backend/suitelet.

I tried to include AWS SDK into Suitelet by  defining, but that doesn't work.

1. I want to get to know whether can we use/include SDKs inside Suitelet?
2. How can I implement a solution for this without using any third party solutions?

Answer (score 0):

How are permissions for the links managed? Can you make them publicly viewable? Remember unless the links you generate are timestamped anyone with the link can get to the image.

In terms of uploading the images check out https://github.com/DeepChannel/netsuite-savedsearch-s3

If you need to keep have each image have a magic link you could use a Heroku app or an AWS lambda. The app would check a hash based on link parameters and proxy the image if the hash is valid. If your images are supposed to be private to a customer this would be the way to go.

If you are using the images generally on a website then just make the bucket publicly readable and use the API to upload.